# Why does the task switcher shows the background app in preview?

Tags: privacy, android, facebook, user-tracking

Normally on android devices, the task switcher shows screenshot of the last state of the app in preview. **But on my device for Facebook, it shows the screenshot of the background app instead of facebook**. ***This makes me skeptical about my privacy***. If Facebook is doing this then they can now track what apps are installed on my phone, or read my content which I last used.

But, *I'm not sure, if this is facebook or the home-launcher/theme pre-installed on my phone by the manufacturer*. This happens only with **FACEBOOK APP**. I tested this on several devices, but this seems to happen only on phones from chinese vendors like, Mi(Xiaomi), Huawei, etc and not on iPhone or Htc.

Would like to know the reason behind this? Thanks.

As you can see in the screenshot, the preview of candy crush is normal whereas for Facebook its showing the background view of homescreen(but it could also be anything from email app, gallery or anything else) instead of my last activity.
Also see the screenshots below: 
[image]

Comment: ... that's not a preview of Facebook but a preview of the folder Facebook is in ...

Comment: this is showing the preview of the folder Facebook is in because thats on the background of Facebook app.... it could be anything.. if I am watching video.. the video will be the background instead of menu

Comment: then that's a local UI thing, not a Facebook app thing - no privacy is being endangered

Comment: then why does it happen with Facebook app only then.... doesnt happen with other apps.. who knows its being accessed by Facebook

Comment: because the UI doesn't know how to hook the app for viewing - if Facebook could access that info, they would do it without 'switcher' being involved

Comment: hmm thanks for the information... confusion is somewhat cleared :-)

Comment: @schroeder true that, it probably is not facebook. But can't it be the launcher doing it? As OP says, It happens with other phones too. So any reason, **how** this might be happening ? And especially, why *only* for facebook ? PS: happens on my phone too.

Comment: @MrClan the launcher has access to everything anyway - I'm not sure how this one UI bug indicates any special compromise

Comment: Agreed that it does not seem much like a compromise of privacy. Just curious about,  the **HOW** though. How this might be happening, and why only with the fb app ?